# How to call a Javascript function onselection of menuitem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, menuitem, onselect

How can I call a Javascript function `test()` as below for the `onselect` event (upon selection of menu item) of a menu item as for my below code?

I have always worked on `OnClick` event in button but I have no idea about `OnSelect` events for the menuitems, how to call a function onselection of menuitem.

Can anyone suggest how can my code below work and call my function `test()` **(code 1)** on selection of menu item named **Log Report** as in  **code-2**?

```
<ul>
<li>Log Report</li>
</ul>
```

**Code-1**

```
<script>
function test() {
    window.open("www.google.com");
}
</script>
```

**Code-2**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test screen</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#menu" ).menu();
});
</script>
<style>
.ui-menu { width: 230px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
<li>Database</li>
<li>Log
<ul>
<li>Log Report</li>
</ul>
</li>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not create a function for every `li`, suggest the use of `data` attribute

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Database</li>
  <li>Log
    <ul>
      <li data-page="www.google.com">Log Report</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then pass it in the function

```
$('#menu li').click(function(){
  test($(this).data('page'));// which will give "www.google.com" if clicked on the Log Report
}

function test(url){
  window.open = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for this

```
    $("#menu").on("click", "li", function(event){
      test();    
      console.log('clicked');
     });
```

Hope this helps...
More info DEMO [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emPKS/)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery UI [Menu](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/) Widget, Use [select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#event-select), it is triggered when a menu item is selected.

```
$('#menu').menu({
    select: function (event, ui) {
        test();
    }
});
```

Another way is

```
$("#menu").on("menuselect", function (event, ui) {
    test();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use click event

```
  $("#menu li").click(function(){
      test();    
     });
```